# Singularity & Snakemake - MissingOutputException

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I am combining Singularity & Snakemake to create a workflow for some sequencing data. I modeled my pipeline after this git project https://github.com/sci-f/snakemake.scif. The version of the pipeline that does not use Singularity runs absolutely fine. The version that uses Singularity always stops after the first rule with the following error:

```
$ singularity run --bind data/raw_data/:/scif/data/ /gpfs/data01/heinzlab/home/cag104/bin/chip-seq-pipeline/chip-seq-pipeline-hg38.simg run snakemake all
[snakemake] executing /bin/bash /scif/apps/snakemake/scif/runscript all
Copying Snakefile to /scif/data
Copying config.yaml to /scif/data
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       bowtie2_mapping
        1       create_bigwig
        1       create_tag_directories
        1       fastp
        1       fastqc
        1       quality_metrics
        1       samtools_index
        8

rule fastp:
    input: THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.fastq.gz
    output: fastp/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.fastp.fastq.gz, fastp_report/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.html, fastp_report/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.json
    log: logs/fastp/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.log
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: sample=THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001

usage: scif run [-h] [cmd [cmd ...]]

positional arguments:
  cmd         app and optional arguments to target for the entry

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 16 of /scif/data/Snakefile:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
fastp/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.fastp.fastq.gz
fastp_report/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.html
fastp_report/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.json
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /scif/data/.snakemake/log/2018-04-06T224320.958604.snakemake.log
```

The directory however does create the fastp and fastp_report directories as well as the logs directory. I tried increasing the latency to 50 seconds, but I still get the same error.

Any ideas on what to try here?

Comment: It appears `shell` or `run` commands are not creating files in the filepath you are expecting. You should check log file `logs/fastp/THP-1_PU1-cMyc_PU1_sc_S40_R1_001.log` to see if it executed without any error. Snakemake always creates required directory at the beginning of rule execution, and hence the empty folders you are seeing.

Comment: @JeeYem the problem appeared to stem from Singularity, and specifically the SCIF architecture and how it runs/executes command line functions. I was able to fix it by simply adding quotes around the shell commands where appropriate as shown in the github I linked. Thanks for helping!